# No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.'

Tags: c#

So, I'm creating a program to check names of a client. But I get this error.
"No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.'"
I'm unsure of what to do at this point, as it's all coded correctly. and I just, I don't understand why it's not working. A friend of mine is running the EXACT same code, and his build worked flawlessly.

Here's my code.

```
        private void PopulateDataGrideView(string Name, string Status)
    {
        if (base.InvokeRequired)
        {
            base.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => {
                DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow = new DataGridViewRow();
                if (Status == "Yes")
                {
                    dataGridViewRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                    Status = "Name Available";
                }
                else if (Status == "No")
                {
                    dataGridViewRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    Status = "Not Available";
                    if (this.VisibilityBx.Checked)
                    {
                        dataGridViewRow.Visible = false;
                    }
                }
                dataGridViewRow.CreateCells(this.checkedNames, new object[] { Name, Status });
                this.checkedNames.Rows.Add(dataGridViewRow);
                if (scrollBx.Checked)
                {
                    this.checkedNames.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = this.checkedNames.RowCount - 1;
                }
                this.progressBar1.Increment(1);
            }));
        }
    }

    private void saveAvailableNamesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> strs = new List<string>();
        if (this.checkedNames.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in (IEnumerable)this.checkedNames.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[1].Value.Equals("Name Available"))
                {
                    strs.Add(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                }
            }
            if (strs.Count > 0)
            {
                string currentDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                File.WriteAllLines(string.Concat(currentDirectory, "\\Available Names ", now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm.ss tt"), ".txt"), strs);
            }
        }
    }

    private void saveTakenNamesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> strs = new List<string>();
        if (this.checkedNames.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in (IEnumerable)this.checkedNames.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[1].Value.Equals("Not Available"))
                {
                    strs.Add(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                }
            }
            if (strs.Count > 0)
            {
                string currentDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                File.WriteAllLines(string.Concat(currentDirectory, "\\Taken Names ", now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm.ss tt"), ".txt"), strs);
            }
        }
    }

    private void scrollBx_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.checkedNames.RowCount > 0)
        {
            if (this.scrollBx.Checked)
            {
                this.checkedNames.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = this.checkedNames.RowCount - 1;
            }
            else if (!this.scrollBx.Checked)
            {
                this.checkedNames.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private void VisibilityBx_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.checkedNames.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in (IEnumerable)this.checkedNames.Rows)
            {
                if (!this.VisibilityBx.Checked)
                {
                    if (!row.Visible)
                    {
                        row.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (this.VisibilityBx.Checked)
                {
                    if ((string)row.Cells[1].Value == "Not Available")
                    {
                        row.Visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void CheckedNames_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)YOURDATAGRIDVIEW.Rows[0].Clone();
```

to create a new row to be added, instead of:

```
DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow = new DataGridViewRow();
```

This preserves the column names in the new row.

You should no longer need this line of code:

```
dataGridViewRow.CreateCells(this.checkedNames, new object[] { Name, Status });
```

Also ensure that data grid view has columns, which is an often cause of this error.

Comment: DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)YOURDATAGRIDVIEW.Rows[0].Clone();
except instead of YOURDATAGRIDVIEW it says my datagridviews name.

Comment: Can you edit and show where you have defined the columns used in your data grid view?